# Auto-method generation in Eclipse/ADT

Tags: android, adt

I'm going through some Android dev tutorials, and in one [particular video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjE-pWYElsE) at about 2:02, he not only autocompletes a method call, but it fills in an entire stub for him at the same time.

It's early on in the tutorials and there's been no mention of a setting to do this - at least it doesn't come natively with my copy of the ADT. Is there an option to turn this on? I haven't found any mention of it in the `Content Assist` menu.

In case it isn't clear - I have a proposal from Eclipse to generate the method call, but NOT the stub method too. I am looking for the added functionality of the stub method being generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `new View.` he clicks on `CTRL` + `SPACE` and then `ENTER` to generate the listener.

Comment: When I do this no proposals come up. I have checked all the Java proposals in `Content Assist - Advanced`

Comment: I also made an edit to the question in case it wasn't clear what I'm looking for.

Comment: It seems as though it is possible to do this by pressing `CTRL` + `SPACE` then typing in the method you want. I can't get it to work after having typed some of the method already though.

Comment: Can you make a screenshot of what you get?